# Cannot install R packages within WRDS Interactive R session

Tags: r, package, wrds

I would like to install the R package 'rstan' in an interactive R session on the WRDS server, but cannot manage to install it, or any other packages.

I have tried specifying the CRAN mirrors directly in the install.packages() command.

I have tried the following within an interactive WRDS session:

```
install.packages("rstan", dep= T)
```

Actual results:

```
install.packages("rstan", dep= T)
```

Installing package into ‘/usr/local/sas/grid/R-3.5.1-linux-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("rsta", dep = T) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/sas/grid/R-3.5.1-linux-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel)

```
yes
```

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---

Then after I pick any mirror, I get:

Warning: unable to access index for repository http://wbc.upm.edu.my/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://wbc.upm.edu.my/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
2: package ‘rstan’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Comment: you might be facing problem with firewall restriction, try opening the url in a browser to check if the link is accessible to you.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I can open the URLs on my laptop; but perhaps the issue is on the WRDS side of it.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to install using the RStudio Server interface (available [here](https://wrds-rstudio.wharton.upenn.edu)). This puts the installed library in the same location that "regular R" uses on the WRDS server. (For me, that's given by the line below.)

That said, when I tried installing `rstan` in this way a moment ago, I got an error message (`dependency ‘V8’ is not available for package ‘rstan’`); some R packages require things that cannot be installed within R.

```
[iangow@wrds-cloud-login1-w 3.6]$ pwd
/home/unimelb/iangow/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6
```